# Is the use of "well"/"poorly" "understood" right in this case without "when it's"?

Tags: comprehension

"It is a very serious thing, well understood it can give life, poorly understood it'll deprive life.".

Comment: It appears to be correct to me, although I would change the comma after *thing* to a full stop.  ***It is a very serious thing.  Well understood it can give life, poorly understood it'll deprive life.***

Comment: @Chris Thank you for helping!
Do you think that I should put "can" after "it" in the last sentence instead of "will"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The punctuation and sentence structure are incorrect—you're using commas to link independent clauses (clauses that can stand alone as independent sentences). I would change it to:

> It is a very serious thing—well understood, it can give life, but, poorly understood, it will deprive life.

You can use a semicolon in place of the dash if you want. I also don't recommend the use of the word deprive without saying what you're depriving life *of*, but I don't want to change the meaning of your sentence. The comma after "but" is due to the absence of "when it's."

EDIT - Other users, please correct me if I'm wrong about the comma after but.

Comment: @YamanKJ I'm not 100% sure about the comma after but; I would consult with other users to make sure.

Comment: Okay, don't worry.
What word would be more accurate and includes the meaning of "Taking one's life (in the mean of depression and angriness not literally dead)"?

Comment: @YamanKJ I'm not aware of a single word that conveys that meaning. Why don't you try thinking about what you're depriving life *of*? E.g. "deprive life of meaning"